# (Node.js/Java) How to make XML output Pretty

Tags: java, node.js, xml, xml-parsing, pretty-print

i have been trying to make output pretty in XML but not able to do so i want to do this in node.js as well as in java(android).

**My XML Input is:**

```
  <custom.TextView 
  android:id="@+id/textView2" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="TextView" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="164dp" />
```

**After parsing this code, output is**

```
<custom.TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="TextView" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="164dp" />
```

**And my expected output is**

```
 <custom.TextView 
  android:id="@+id/textView2" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="TextView" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="164dp" />
```

how can i do this pleas help me !

Comment: This is a little unclear. How do you produce this output? Do you print it yourself? Is it in an editor and you want to format it?

Comment: Very few XML serializers stack attributes vertically the way you show. One that does in Saxon, though (a) it doesn't do it exactly the way you would like, and (b) it's not available on your chosen platforms. I think if you really want this layout you may have to code it yourself.

Comment: Well I have been trying from 2 weeks, basically I'm doing parsing of xml using xmldom in node.js, parsing is done but format is changed for all tags, how can I preserve the format, this is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although approach used in this scenario is not very good but you can try this code for pretty output, in below code you can provide your xml, it'll then beautify it as you desire.

```
    var arrayEml= xml = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
        if ((xml[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) && (xml[i + 1] == ' ') && (xml[i + 2].match(/[a-zA-Z]/))) {
            arrayEml += (xml[i] + '\n');
        } else {
            arrayEml += xml[i];
        }
        // }
    }
    var againParsing = ' ';
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayEml.length; i++) {

        if ((xml[i] = '"') && (xml[i + 1] == ' ') && (xml[i + 2].match(/[a-zA-Z]/))) {
            againParsing += (xml[i] + '\n' + "\t   ");
        } else {
            againParsing += xml[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it completely solved my problem, thankyou so much :) <3